I am having trouble figuring out how to round a number to the nearest ones place in p5.js
I have a game I'm making in p5.js and I am having trouble rounding my health varible to the nearest ones place.
I tried using p5.js's round() function (https://p5js.org/reference/p5/round/) and it isn't fitting my problem. I don't think you can use the round() function for variables, I think you use it for just strings. I did
let health = round(100)

the result was an error
I expected the variable to be rounded

This question is unclear. round() works on numbers--can you explain your use case, input and actual/expected output? Thanks.

I think you use it for just strings. - and yet, the page you linked to shows no strings being rounded

edited, thank you.

round(100) should give 100--it's already rounded to 100. round(100.16) gives 100. That's how it normally works.

Variables can store either numbers and strings.

the result was an error what was the error?

round() takes the value of whatever is inside it, and rounds it to the nearest ones place automatically.
round() does work on variables. If you want to use it that way, put the variable in the parenthesis:
round(health)

This returns the value of the variable automatically rounded to the nearest ones place. (For other decimal places, add a second parameter. The number 1 in the second parameter would cause the number to round to the nearest tenths place.) Then, use this in either a parameter of a different function or another variable.
(In the following examples, I am using another health variable (health2) to be the rounded form of health. You don't need to do this necessarily.)
In addition, you can't set a variable's value to round or similar things like floor() or ceil() outside functions. So, do one of the following options:
Either move the variable declaration into one of the functions (i.e. the draw function) like so:
let health = 1.5;
function draw() {
    let health2 = round(health)
}

Or use the slightly different way, which is to declare the variable outside any functions, but change it to be the rounded value inside a function, like so:
let health = 1.5;
let health2;
function draw() {
    health2 = round(health)
}

If you need any clarification, go to p5js's page about round()
